# How to say "on page x and the following pages"?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to refer to a certain page and the pages after that, but without giving the end as a specified number.

Can I use these phrases?

> [...] can be found on page x and the following.

> [...] can be found on page x and the following pages.

> [...] can be found after page x?

I personally don't like the second version. Is the first version correct? Can I use it?

Answer (score 5):

Your first example is perfectly fine because "pages" isn't necessary. You've already stated that you're referring to pages when you say, "found on *page* x".

I assume that you want to spell out this information particularly instead of using the ff. notation:

"... can be found on page xff."

which means the same thing.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ff.

Comment: Is ff a British English convention? I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: It's commonly used on footnotes in the US. I think you'd rarely see it in the body of the text unless other similar abbreviations were also used. Note by "xff" he means a number followed by "ff", like "page 10 ff".

Comment: Note if you're spelling it out you should just write, "page 10 and following", not "and THE following".

Comment: @Daniel: No. It is common inside publishing, but not elsewhere, and probably wouldn't be understood by most British English readers. See here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115784/is-the-latin-abbreviation-f-folio-commonly-used-in-page-ranges/115803#115803

Comment: I recognize it, but these things are hit-or-miss. Those who have seen it before will recognize it immediately, but those who haven't will be confused.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's overly simple for your needs but I would always say:

> ...can be found from page x onwards

Answer (score 2):

I'd say one of the following:
• ... can be found on page x and following
• ... can be found on page x [et seq.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_seq.)
• ... can be found on or after page x

Answer (score 1):

Not “page 42 and the following”. The adjective *following* calls for a noun. It looks like you're using “the following” to mean “what follows the current point in the text” or “something that follows” or “the next few lines”.

“Page 42 and the following pages” sounds correct. This could be shortened to “page 42 and following pages” (since you aren't specifying the exact number of following pages, it's *some* following pages, so the null article works), or perhaps even to “page 42 and following” (without *the*, it doesn't look like a noun is missing any more).

In practice, you would normally not spell this out, but use the abbreviation *[ff.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ff.#English)* The word *page* becomes plural since it now designates not just to the first page but to the whole sequence.

> (…) can be found on pages 42ff."

Comment: Is ff a British English convention? I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not aware of its being more British than American. It seems to be going out of style however. See [this answer by StoneyB](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115784/is-the-latin-abbreviation-f-folio-commonly-used-in-page-ranges/115803#115803) (which mentions that the US Modern Language Association documents but deprecates *ff.*).

Comment: -1. Most British and American English readers would probably find *10ff* more confusing than "pages 10 onwards", which would be more common. English Learners would be well advised to use simple, understandable English than arcane shorthands that are not in wide idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 1):

Even in an academic paper, I think you can avoid esoteric notation like *ff* or *et seq*.  (Or perhaps especially in an academic paper.  Contrary to popular opinion, you don't win points for making a paper hard to read.)  You can express this simply, and I would do so by writing "starting on":

> [...] can be found *starting on* page 153.

There are some good alternatives in the other answers.  Just make sure that however you choose to express yourself, it's clear to your intended audience.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is better than your first example, IMO. You could say

> "[...] can be found on page x and on.

which would mean the same thing (although "and on" could possibly be taken to mean "until the end of the book").

Saying "after page x" is confusing. It probably would not include page x, but it is ambiguous enough that someone would probably have to ask for clarification.

Comment: Would it not be more common to say "From page 10 onwards?"

Comment: @Matt I've heard them both, but "and on" sounds more natural to me than "onwards".

Comment: Matt, it seems so. That's a good suggestion and would be worth posting as an answer.